# Prestashop : Link to database cannot be established

Tags: php, mysql, database, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have to handle the finishing of a prestashop website that is almost done and it's the first time I ever use prestashop, and I'm not very familiar with PHP and MySQL.

I have downloaded the site in local but When I launch MAMP Pro, and get to

```
http://localhost:8888/www/<mysite>/index.php
```

I get only this :

```
Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pshop'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Prestashop's email says :

```
MySQL admin account : root
MySQL admin password : <adminpw>

MySQL database for Prestashop : prestashop
MySQL account for the Prestashop base : pshop
Password for the Prestashop MySQL account : <accountpw>
```

and in config/settings.php I have :

```
<?php
define('_DB_SERVER_', 'localhost');
define('_DB_NAME_', 'ps5');
define('_DB_USER_', 'pshop');
define('_DB_PASSWD_', '<accountpw>');
```

Actually I can see in phpMyAdmin that there are 2 db, one called `prestashop` and one called `ps5`. From what I can see they have the same definitions (same users, same clients) so I just changed `ps5` into prestashop in config/settings.php, but none of them works anyway.

Is there another file where this appears and I should change it to harmonize everything ?
Should I change the db account password "just in case it's different" in phpmyadmin ? I'm a bit worried about possible consequences if it's not the right thing to do and i can not go back.
Is there a way in phpmyadmin to just *check what are the current passwords for accounts or db's?

Inside phpmyadmin > left pannel > prestashop (or ps5, same result) > right bar, "privileges" :

User "pshop" on client "localhost", type "global", has all privileges, but has no "Grant", and I can not set it to yes :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'pshop'@'localhost'WITH GRANT OPTION MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;

#1045 - Access denied for user 'pshop'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And,

mysql_error.log file in Mamp pro says :

```
160408 0:14:08 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Normal shutdown

160408 0:14:08 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
160408 0:14:08 InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
160408 0:14:09 InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 50703588
160408 0:14:09 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160408 00:14:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
160408 10:10:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
160408 10:10:21 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
160408 10:10:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
160408 10:10:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160408 10:10:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160408 10:10:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
160408 10:10:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160408 10:10:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160408 10:10:21 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
160408 10:10:22 InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160408 10:10:23 InnoDB: 5.5.42 started; log sequence number 50703588
160408 10:10:23 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160408 10:10:23 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.42' socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' port: 0 Source distribution
```

Apache error log says :

```
[Fri Apr 08 00:14:10 2016] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Apr 08 10:05:20 2016] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Fri Apr 08 10:05:20 2016] [notice] Digest: done
[Fri Apr 08 10:05:21 2016] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 492)
[Fri Apr 08 10:05:21 2016] [notice] Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/2.7.10 PHP/5.6.10 mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/0.9.8za DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_perl/2.0.9 Perl/v5.22.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

and php error log says nothing about today where i still have my problem

can it be a problem in my mamp pro config ?

• In mamp pro there is a MySQL tab and there is a button "change the root password", should I do it ?

It says "for safety reasons the password of the "root" mysql user must be changed when you connect to the internet"

but I'm just trying to work locally so I don't think I should do this ?

• Still in Mamp pro, I have a choice:

Execute Apache/MySQL server as a user :

- jeremieg (Apache) / jeremieg (MySQL)

(jeremieg is my name and my mac book name)

or :

- www (Apache) / mysql (MySQL) > This one is choosen by default

(none of them works anyway)

• Still in Mamp Pro :

```
- Default Apache port for http connections : 8888

- Default Apache port for https connections (SSL) : 8890

- MySQL port : 8889
```

But still, today when I clicked on "start the servers" in Mamp, because Apache was on but MySQL was off after I launched Mamp,

I had an alert saying port 80 was already used (strange because I was not asking for port 80), and that it could cause conflict with one of my virtual machines and so I should change the port; but I chose "Start the servers anyway" and it launched MySQL.

I also tried loading the index.php after disabling little snitch, just in case (and emptying cache), but it didn't change.

Comment: do you still get the error if you use `root` as user (and the root password) in `config.php`?

Comment: my only memories of MAMP, which i thankfully haven't used in years, is that anything other than the most basic sites never worked :(

Comment: haha thank you that gives me hope ;) yes i tried too and now it says unknown database, while the database actually IS on phpmyadmin

Comment: hm... try the following: log in to phpmyadmin as root, click on the `Users` tab, click on `Add user`, choose any unique name, let's say "mampsux", host: localhost, passwort: whatever, then check the box that says "Create database with same name and grant all privileges", scroll down and click go. This will create a database with the same name as the user ("mampsux") import one of your other DB's into that empty DB, try with these settings in `config.php`

Comment: gonna try and let you know, thanks

Comment: when you say connect to phpmyadmin as root, you mean user name "root" password "root", or you mean the main user the website's database ? because root / root doesn't work

Comment: oh right the default mysql root password is probably (nothing) so just type in user "root" and leave the password field blank

Comment: ok gonna try - hey when I am in phpmyadmin, if i don't get into a database but directly click on users, I have : 

  user prestashop  client localhost  Password No(written in red)  and everyone has global privileges All privileges but this one has global privilege USAGE  

and I can not change it as it answers : #1045 - Access denied for user 'pshop'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 

What do you think ?

Comment: and i cannot connect with root even with blank field for password

Comment: well since you are able to log in to phpmyadmin just try the steps above (create new user with a password and check the box to create a DB) as whatever user you are logged in as.

Comment: I now have "Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"…

Comment: well is the DB still empty? did you export one of the old prestashp DB's (`prestashop` or `ps5`) and import one of them into the newly created DB?

Comment: yes i did succesfully, it did import it…

Comment: i now had prestashop on phone and they said i should important the database file locally, but they didn't say how to do it, so i'm searching their docs but they don't seem to explain it…

Comment: and now anyway since i created a new database it always says no such file or directory, even though i modified the php file back to the original names and saved it… either it's a good sign meaning i have no more password problem, but now i just have to get my db somewhere, either it means something is totally out of its way

Comment: honestly this is getting more complicated, your best bet is probably to backup everything you have, and start from scratch, including reinstalling MAMP and setting everything up cleanly

Comment: yeah, that's exactly what i was starting to do - my only worry is that it was all brand new when problems appeared, they didn't arrive like after some operations, so i'm afraid the "from scratch" configuration will bring the same problems exactly again…

Comment: hey does this look like a problem to you ? in the settings.inc.php file : define('_MYSQL_ENGINE_', 'InnoDB');

Comment: ok no, sorry, it's just part of mysql - but now when i use my own new db and username and password, the ones i created above, it also says : Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mouilocal'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: and now MAMP won't start APache anymore and can't find my IP anymore… I love this